# Python script not sending request params

Tags: python, http, post, request, httplib

I'm trying to send a POST request to my server. The server is reached. I can see that by the servers response but the parameters are not sent. 
The request needs the params in a JSON object.

```
params = "{'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0}"

c = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
userAndPass = b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass }

c.request('POST',url, params, headers=headers)
res = c.getresponse()
data = res.read()  

print(data)
```

I've checked on my server function and the params are not sent there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing params in your server function correctly.

To simply view what message is sent to server you can simply run a simple server with **nc** command in terminal:

```
nc -l -p 1234
```

then with executing your code and sending request to localhost:1234 you can see that this message is sent:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 34
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=

{'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0}
```

So your params are sent but you don't access them in a correct way in your server function.

Answer (score 1):

Correct headers were not set

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass }
```